# A generalization of coupon collector problem - $\geq1$ pick per experiment

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, asymptotics, measure-concentration, lower-bounds

Mix $T\geq1$ coupons numbered $1$ to $T$ with a set of $S\geq0$ number of dummy coupons with no numbers. Select $N\geq1$ coupons at each trial at random and put them back.

**$N=1$ is standard coupon collector problem. I have not seen any reference for $N>1$.**

**1.** What is the probability that after $k$ trials you selected each coupon from $1$ to $T$ at least once?

**2.** What is the expected number of trials one needs to select each coupon from $1$ to $T$ at least once with probability $1-\frac{1}{c}$ for some $c>1$?

**3.** Fix a coupon $x_t\in\{1,\dots,T\}$. How many trials to do you expect to have to select this particular coupon at least once with probability $1-\frac{1}{c}$ for some $c>1$?

I am looking for sharp asymptotics.

Comment: Not an asymptotic but exact answer for question 1: $$\binom{T+S}{N}^{-k} \sum_{i=0}^T (-1)^i \binom{T}{i} \binom{T-i+S}{N}^k.$$

Comment: If $N=1$ then the expectation is $(S+T)H_T$

Comment: @Henry Yes. $N=1$ is standard. What about $N>1$?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I am not getting prob <1? Could you write your proof?

Comment: @Arul: What are your numerical values? The formula follows from the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: I tried $k=Log2[1000]$, $T=N=(S+T)/k=1000/k$ in mathematica. Infact it goes to $<0$ if $10000$ replaces $1000$.

Comment: It is $>0$ at $499$, $<0$ at $498$.

Comment: @Arul: I do not understand what is 499 in here. Can you give numerical (integer) values of each of the parameters when the expression becomes negative?
Just in case here is my PARI/GP code: { pr(T,S,N,k) = sum(i=0,T, (-1)^i * binomial(T,i) * binomial(T-i+S,N)^k ) / binomial(T+S,N)^k }

Comment: Instead of 1000 I took 499 or 498. I used mathematica.